# Lightroom Library Metadata filter does not show result count

Tags: lightroom

I have Lightroom installed on 2 devices. When I use the Metadata library filter (e.g. on keywords etc) it would should me the number of results on one device (see lower image) but not on the other (upper image). Where is the setting for this?

thanks!

[image: no count]
[image: with count]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be based on the width of the Lightroom window. With LR maximized on my desktop, it shows the counts, but if I shrink the window down some, or expand the size of the sidebars, they disappear, even when there is still plenty of room to show them. This seems like a bug.

I reported this on the Adobe forums. https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/library-filter-counts-disappearing

Answer (score 1):

This was confirmed as a bug by Adobe engineers. It was introduced in Lightroom 8.0 on Windows.

https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/library-filter-panel-stops-showing-number-of-images-in-each-category